# soapUI: multipart/form-data REST request with file attachments

Tags: rest, testing, soapui

I am using soapUI for testing a REST web service. Is there a way to attach a file with the other parameters in a multipart request? I see the attachment tab in the panel but I cannot give that attachment a parameter name so that server can identify. It's not helping.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found it but forgot to post it here. It was not so intuitive.

1. In your REST Request if you can see an attachment tab, open it and add and attachment with + button. The Name of that file would show full path. e.g. `C:\temp\my-file.csv`
2. In you parameters tab, add a parameter and give it a name. The value of that parameter will be `file:C:\temp\my-file.csv`
3. In SoapUI 5.x and greater, you must select the "Post QueryString" checkbox. Without this, the file will not be send along with the request.

That should be it. When attaching a file if you select Yes when it asks to Cache the file, you won't have to specify full path in step 2 above. The value of file parameter should be `file:my-file.csv`

Comment: Do you have any idea about send a JSON content also with the attachemnt using soapUI?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, you will need to send your JSON content as a parameter. Create parameters for your JSON content and for your attachment.

Comment: in SOapUI 5.0.0 you must check the `Post querystring` option

Comment: Do you need to specify enable Inline Files for REST API service? Is there any option somewhere? I get the error "Cannot parse XML document" when trying to attach an XML file.

Comment: Do you have Media Type set to "multipart/form-data" and Post QueryString.. checkbox checked?

Comment: Just to clarify and complete the answer to the question **How to add JSON content along with an attachment in a POST multipart/form-data request using soapUI?** (@JavaGuy and @bluetech)..

**Prerequisites:**

1. **POST** request.

2. Media Type: multipart/form-data.

3. **Post QueryString** is checked/activated.

4. An attachment added via Attachments menu

In soapUI 5.2.1 open source (currently the latest release), you must add a query parameter as in the following example:

`Name: request; Value: {"yourJson":"goesHere"}; Style: QUERY; Level: RESOURCE`

Comment: For the part **I see the attachment tab in the panel but I cannot give that attachment a parameter name so that server can identify. It's not helping.**.... 

The parameter name that will be matchable in the WS through `@FormDataParam("attachment") InputStream attachment....` must be set in the **ContentID** column in the Attachments tab: the value could be "attachment" - that would work with the snippet above.

Answer (score -4):

select mediatype as application/json and then add the json string to that. It will go to server as payload. Usually this request is of POST or PUT type

Comment: This answer does not address the question which is about "file attachments"