# multipart/form-data post request is not working on SoapUI but works fine in Postman

Tags: soap, postman, soapui

I'm testing a multipart/forma-data request to upload a file(image-jpg, doc, etc) in SOAP UI. It gives 200 success message but does not uploads the file. The same request is working fine through the Postman tool.

I followed the same steps which are mentioned at most of the forum's to resolve such issues with the attachments in SOAP UI. I am adding one of the link below which I referred while configuring this on SOAP UI.

[soapUI: multipart/form-data REST request with file attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467901/soapui-multipart-form-data-rest-request-with-file-attachments)

My configuration in SOAP UI is as below -
[SOAP UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45a2S.png)

The only difference I can see with respect to Postman is that the SOAP UI generates the boundaries for multipart-form-data differently. It does not add boundary end tag after the contents. I am not sure if that is an issue here.

Comment: Have you added a test case in the project?

Comment: Yes, I have test suite with above test case.

Comment: The `ContentID` must match the the part after `file:`, so `flower.jpg` in your case.

Comment: Please follow the suggestion by @SiKing. Refer documentation for the same https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/attachments.html

Comment: I am testing restful api endpoints. It looks like the link above is for soap-wsdl related services. I do not see mtom request options for restful tests. However, the other steps mentioned there looks to be the same which I followed.