# SOAP UI - Return two different responses for two different POST Request Payloads for same REST API end point

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a REST POST API end point - "abc/def".
It's request payload has (out of many other fields) a field "yourId" which can take either 1 or 2 as shown below:

```
{
  "yourId":"1"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "yourId":"2
}
```

On the basis of the value of "yourId", I need to return two different responses either 1. YOUR_RESPONSE_1 OR 2. YOUR_RESPONSE_2 for which I have written a groovy script as shown below:

```
def requestBody = mockRequest.getRequestContent()
log.info "Request body: " + requestBody
yourId="yourId"
id1="1"
id2="2"
if(requestBody.contains(yourId+":"+id1)){
    return "YOUR_RESPONSE_1"
}else if(requestBody.contains(yourId+":"+id2)){
    return "YOUR_RESPONSE_2"
}else return "ERROR_RESPONSE"
```

When I hit the end point "localhost:8080/abc/def" from postman, I get ERROR_RESPONSE. How can I fix it.

Comment: I have solved this issue - my mistakes - 1. `yourId="\"yourId\""`, 
2 `id1="\"1\""`, 
3. `id2="\"2\""`

Comment: Hey @log0 - Did you try out the alternative suggestion ?

Comment: @WilfredClement Yes. That's working great.

Comment: With my solution the problem is `"yourId":"1"` should have NO SPACE in between. But your solution works great beyond this constraint.

Comment: @WilfredClement  I need to provide a multipart file attachment in this api. I have seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467901/soapui-multipart-form-data-rest-request-with-file-attachments ans but that's too old.  Would you help me to achieve that

Comment: The information is a bit broad, can you raise a new question with detailed information and let me know and I can look into it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the JSONSlurper() as this avoids the use of escape characters and makes the script legible, Also it come in handy when the input JSON is complex

```
def requestBody = mockRequest.getRequestContent()
def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(requestBody)
def ID =  parsedJson.yourId

if(ID=="1"){
    return "YOUR_RESPONSE_1"
}
else if(ID=="2"){
    return "YOUR_RESPONSE_2"
}
else return "ERROR_RESPONSE"
```