# SOAP UI - Attaching a multipart file in request body of rest api

Tags: rest, soapui, attachment, multipart, form-data

In SOAP UI, I need to attach a multipart file in a rest api. I have stored responses for this api.  I have seen this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467901/soapui-multipart-form-data-rest-request-with-file-attachments) but could not get much help. I know that multipart files are sent in form-data. The documentation talks about some "attachment tab" but I can't find that in my case as I have stored responses - this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465542/soap-ui-return-two-different-responses-for-two-different-post-request-payloads?noredirect=1#comment110657614_62465542) gives an idea about my rest api.

Comment: @WilfredClement pls have a look here

Comment: Hey @log0 - I am still not very clear with the requirement, Your first question was how to dispatch a response but here you are wanting to attach a file to the request ? Do you mean when  `return "YOUR_RESPONSE_1"` should return you a file ?

Comment: @WilfredClement No. I want to attach a multipart (audio) file in the request payload to be sent to backend. For example - through postman we mention a key in the form-data field and choose its type as file.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/attachments/) and let me know if it helps

Comment: @WilfredClement I have seen the documentation but I can't find "Attachments Tab"? does that come with pro version?

Comment: No, it is present in the open soure version too, Check the bottom tab of your request pane and the 3rd option is "attachments"

Comment: @WilfredClement In the attachment tab I am able to attach an image file. But how can I send a multipart/form-data and json body together?